# std::bad_alloc error in C++ vector in merge sort

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to implement merge sort using vector in c++, i am getting following error - 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'.
There were other solutions for bad_alloc but it didn't help.

problem is merging function-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void print(vector<int> v)
{
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

vector<int> merging(vector<int> left, vector<int> right)
{
    vector<int> result;
    while((int)left.size()>0 && (int)right.size()>0)
    {
        if((int)left.front()<=(int)right.front()){
            result.push_back(left.front());
            //left.erase(left.begin());
        }
        else{
            result.push_back(right.front());
            //left.erase(right.begin());
        }
    }
        while((int)left.size()>0){
            for(int j=0; j<(int)left.size(); j++)
                result.push_back(left[j]);
        }
        while((int)right.size()>0){
            for(int k=0; k<(int)right.size(); k++)
                result.push_back(right[k]);
        }
    cout << "check merging";
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a, b, result;
    a.push_back(38);
    a.push_back(27);
    b.push_back(43);
    b.push_back(3);
    cout << a.front() << endl;
    print(a);
    cout << endl;
    print(b);
    cout << endl;
    result = merging(a, b);
    print(result);
}
```

thank you

Comment: In merging() you look to be in an infinite loop (actually there are several infinite loops). Well one that keeps inserting until your virtual memory has been exhausted.

Comment: BTW, since you are not removing any items from left or write result will be a vector containing the same item in every element.

Answer (score 2):

From the page on [`std::bad_alloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/bad_alloc/)

> Type of the exceptions thrown by the standard definitions of operator new and operator new[] when they fail to allocate the requested storage space.

You're running out of memory and an exception is being thrown when you can't allocate anymore.

Try taking a look at the exit conditions for your loops.

```
while((int)left.size()>0 && (int)right.size()>0)
```

This loop won't exit until both `left` and `right` are empty, however you're never changing their size (the `erase` calls are commented out).

The other two while loops have similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

The first while loop never terminates.  It keeps adding elements to result until the memory is exhausted.

There are other issues with your code:
In the case of left.front() <= right.front you never remove the element you put in result from left, it is commented out.
In that else, you do not remove from `right` either.  The commented out code would remove from `left`, mixing an iterator from `right` into an erase from `left`, what is technically called "undefined behavior" meaning that your program is toast.

Also, why do you cast to int everywhere? that's so unnecessary

Even if you would erase from the front of left and right, you would use vectors for removing from the front, operations that are not supported efficiently by a vector.  There is no need to do that, you can traverse `left` and `right` using iterators, checking instead of whether they are empty for whether the left iterator reached the end of `left` and whether the right iterator reached the end of `right`

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop.

```
while((int)left.size()>0 && (int)right.size()>0)
{
    if((int)left.front()<=(int)right.front()){
        result.push_back(left.front());
        //left.erase(left.begin());
    }
    else{
        result.push_back(right.front());
        //left.erase(right.begin());
    }
}
```

Is never going to end as you never remove any elements from `left`